# Failed to copy C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.0\harness\etc\Info.plist

Tags: netbeans

I am trying to use Netbeans 7.0 today but it keeps on failing with:

```
C:\project\build.xml:14: Failed to copy C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.0\harness\etc\Info.plist to C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.0\harness\etc\Info.plist.original due to java.io.FileNotFoundException C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.0\harness\etc\Info.plist.original (Accès refusé)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug to be [filed](http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html) if your so inclined.  As to why it's failing, it looks as if you have [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) (User Account Control) turned on and the file in question is inside a directory that can't be written to without elevating your permissions.

A temporary work around is to run NetBeans as an Administrator by right clicking on the shortcut you're using to launch it.  This would give you the ability to write to that location.  Once you've successfully built the project I would recommend that you restart NetBeans under your normal account.